# XUL overlay used in different places in the same window?

Tags: overlay, xul

I'm trying to create an interface with three tabboxes where the user can choose in which tabbox he wants  which tabs.

Is this at all possible using overlays?

Is there a way of editing the content of the parent in the overlay file before its loaded... or do I need to write a slightly different overlay for each tabbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a scenario where you would use [XBL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Introduction_to_XBL) rather than overlays.